# OpenCV Template Matching - How to determine the angle of the matched template

Tags: opencv, template-matching

I'm using OpenCV template matching for an industrial pattern matching scenario. How can I determine the angle between my template image and the display image? My routine is using matchTemplate -> normalize -> minMaxLoc. Can anyone please give me an idea or a code example on how to achieve this? Thank you.

Comment: Try using Log-Polar template matching.  It accounts for rotation.  This post on DSP StackExchange may provide some insight: http://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/6194/scale-and-rotation-invariant-template-matching

Answer (score 2):

Template matching, as implemented in OpenCV, is not invariant to rotation. It is design only for translation. Thus anything beyong a very small rotation will not be detected [reliably] by template-matching at all.

You will need an alternative approach if you have to account for rotation.
Some options include:

- Trying multiple template rotations;
- If you know the axis of rotation, then you can use log-polar representation (as @rayryeng suggests in the comments)
- Use a rotationally invariant descriptor.